# Indexing every occurrence of a key in an array of strings with perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have an array of strings @Sentences and I am trying to find the best way to index each occurrence of every word with respect to the line number they are on. I thought to do this with a nested for loop and 2 dimensional array but have had no luck.

Comment: Could you include the code you tried to use?

Comment: Could you also include some sample text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming words are space-delimited (adjust as needed)

```
my $index = {};
my $line=0;
for my $s (@Sentences)
{
    $line++;
    for my $w (split $s)
    {
        push @{$index->{$w}},$line;
    }
}
```

This creates a hash whose keys are the words and whose values are arrayrefs containing lists of line numbers in which those words appear.

Comment: With this how could I sort the hash by amount of numbers in the list so it could be printed?

Comment: `for my $key (sort {@{ $index->{$a} } <=> @{ $index->{$b} } keys %$index)`